# Windows 10 home server RAID errors

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, raid

First of all apologies in advance, I am still learning about the different ways to setup a home server. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I recently converted an old PC I had into a home media server. Here are the specs:

Windows 10 Pro
Intel Core i3-7100 3.90 GHz, 3.91 GHz
4GB RAM
64 bit OS

I then installed 4 x Western Digital Red 4TB (WDC WD40EFRX-68N32N0) drives into the machine via SATA. In Windows 10, I went to Manage storage spaces and created a storage space using a file system of NTFS and a Resiliency type of "Parity". I chose this resilience type as it allows maximum data as well as some security in terms of hard drive failure...

I am now trying to copy all of my data to this new storage pool, and have been having relative success until just now where all of a sudden, after copying about 4TB of data at the very end, the disk just disappears and I get an Error: "Offline due to critical write failures; add drives". This is the second time this has happened to me when I restart the computer the drive is back to normal.

[Error which appears shown in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrza8.jpg)

1. Why is this happening? Does this mean an HDD is on its way out already? If so how can I figure out which one it is? I JUST had a brand new HDD replaced from WD as it was clicking and took over a month to get it replaced. Really dont want to go through that again so soon!!!
2. Is a parity resilience RAID type OK to use for my situation? I plan on also mirroring my files up to a cloud service as a last resort backup.
3. Are WD Red drives worth it? Should I have looked for another drive to use?
4. Is having a 16TB RAID recommend? Or should I have split them up into smaller amounts for data safety?

Thanks for any help you can offer

Kim

Comment: Before assuming that the drive is bad, also check your cables. Does the problem move to another drive when you swap a cable? Or use a different SATA port? And ofc, as suggested, read the SMART status.

Comment: Thanks both for answering me. I ended up buying a SilverStone ECS01 LSI Raid controller to get around the failings of software RAID. It has been working a treat this past couple of months. Can anyone recommend some software which will assist me in keeping an eye on the RAIDs health? Is there a solution out there to get a warning if a disk is on its way out or dies?

Comment: In general disk errors and or warnings will be logged in the event viewer. However I always installed the default software which came with my HW RAID cards and had that software email me if something happened.

Comment: Not sure my RAID controller came with software, any ideas where I can find the software for the SilverStone ECS01 LSI Raid controller?

Comment: On windows? No idea. I only used pre bundled on windows and native tools on BSD.

Answer (score 0):

1. I encountered this a few times. **Storage spaces is generally bugged**.
   You should of created your RAID from the controller.
2. It's fine as a solution.
3. WD Reds are quite reliable. Just to make sure they are fine, read their SMART statuses with something like HDTune.
4. Yes, but **make it from the RAID controller, not window**s.

That being said, there are many patches / updates related to storage spaces. 
You should install [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2887595/windows-rt-8-1--windows-8-1--and-windows-server-2012-r2-update-rollup) and [this other one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2897150/storage-spaces-volumes-go-offline-and-then-online-continuously-in-wind) for start.